# syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing

I'm practicing Codeigniter PHP Framework, also I'm very new to it.
I have created View (login.php) in view folder of Framework.
My issue is that I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Please check the code with what is the syntax error into it.

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php if($error==1){ ?>
<p>Your username / password did not match.</p>
<? } ?>
<form action="<?=base_url?>users/login" method="post">
    <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: easy: short tag syntax

Comment: Question name is same. but content error is different.

Comment: Fred can you please explain me like how?

Comment: Just read the duplicate.

Comment: This: `<? } ?>` won't work if you don't have "short tags" enabled. Use `<?php } ?>` instead.

Comment: what is = in this code <?=base_url?>

Comment: `<?=base_url?>` is short tag syntax which is equivalent to `<?php echo base_url?>`

Comment: Thanks it works !!! :)

Comment: action="<?php echo base_url ?>/users/login"

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant base_url - assumed 'base_url'

Comment: `action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/users/login"` you missed the `()` - `base_url()` is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

Firstly, you are using short tag syntax when it hasn't been enabled on your system.

Consult the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Then your form's `action="<?=base_url?>users/login"`

or as stated in comments `action="<?php echo base_url ?>/users/login"` with the extra slash.

You missed the `()` in order to declare it as a function.

- `base_url()` is a function so you need to add the `()` to it, which is why you're getting the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Use of undefined constant base_url - assumed 'base_url'

as stated in comments.

Additional documentation:

- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html